# Php include once generates error

Tags: php

My file structure looks like this:

```
Lib
  -Models
     b.php
     c.php
  -Controllers
     a.php
```

In the a.php file I want to include b.php. How do I do this? Everything I try generates errors of this sort:

> failed to open stream: No such file or directory

I've tried:

```
include_once '..\Models\b.php';
include_once '\..\Models\b.php';
include_once $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] .'\Models\b.php';
include_once __DIR__ .'\Models\b.php';
```

& some others

EDIT!
Forward slashes don't work either. I've also tried the following:

```
include_once '../Models/b.php';
include_once '/../Models/b.php';
include_once $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] .'/Models/b.php';
include_once __DIR__ .'/Models/b.php';
```

Comment: Use slash instead of backslash.

Comment: @MrTux I've tried that and it doesn't work.

Comment: Have you echo'ed `__DIR__` for debugging purposes?

Comment: What is your `DOCUMENT_ROOT` set to? You may need to use `$_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] .'/Lib/Models/b.php';`

Comment: I think this should be `include_once __DIR__ .'\..\Models\b.php';` (with ..\).  Also check it's the correct case - some file systems are case sensitive.

Answer (score 0):

First up, find out which directory the code running the include is in:

```
die(var_dump(__DIR__));
```

Then, you'll know whether to go into or drop out of whichever folder you are in.

Use `realpath($stringPath);` to convert strings like `/var/www/site/something/../data/file.php` to the real path, `/var/www/site/data/file.php`

It's also worth defining a `WEB_ROOT` constant you could use:

```
define('WEB_ROOT', $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']);
```

Then you can say `require_once realpath(WEB_ROOT.$filePath);`